# Create Stored Procedure with VB.NET

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, stored-procedures

I am trying to complete a procedure in VB.NET that makes a copy of a SQL database and creates all of the database objects (tables, function and stored procedures).  I can create the database successfully and for the tables, I load a script from a text file using the following code:

```
    Dim strConnection As String = myConnectionString
    Dim objCon As New SqlConnection(strConnection)
    Dim objCmd As SqlCommand = Nothing
    Dim sr As StreamReader = Nothing
    Dim sb As System.Text.StringBuilder = Nothing
    Dim line As String = ""
    Dim ScriptFileNames(5) As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim filename As String
    ScriptFileNames(1) = "CreateTables.sql"
    ScriptFileNames(2) = "CreateStoredProcedures.sql"
    ScriptFileNames(3) = "CreateFunctions.sql"

    For i = 1 To 1
        filename = SysConfig.DBScriptLocation & ScriptFileNames(i)

        sr = New StreamReader(filename)

        sb = New System.Text.StringBuilder
        Do While sr.Peek() <> -1
            line = sr.ReadLine()
            If (line = "GO" Or line Is Nothing Or line Is System.DBNull.Value) Then
                ' do nothing 
            Else
                If line Is System.DBNull.Value Then
                    sb.Append(ControlChars.CrLf & " ")
                Else
                    sb.Append(ControlChars.CrLf & line)                        
                End If
            End If
        Loop

        ' Create the database            
        objCon.Open()
        objCmd = objCon.CreateCommand()
        ' Execute            
        objCmd.CommandText = sb.ToString
        objCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        objCon.Close()
    Next
```

This works great for all of the tables but always bombs for stored procedures.  My text file looks like:

CREATE  PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertDeal](
    @DealID as int)

AS

BEGIN

INSERT INTO Table1 (DealID, LoanID) 
SELECT @DealID as DealID, LOAN_ID
FROM ImportedLoans

INSERT INTO Table2 (DealID, LoanID) 
SELECT @DealID as DealID, LOAN_ID
FROM ImportedLoans

END

CREATE PROCEDURE SProc2 
AS
BEGIN
Code for SProc2 .....
END

CREATE PROCEDURE SProc23
AS
BEGIN
Code for SProc3 .....
END 
 etc etc

My code bombs on the "GO" so I removed the "GO" statements but it still does not run and I get messages about @DealID not being defined.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks

Comment: Was this intentional -- `For i = 1 To 1` ? You are only reading your table script and not the other scripts.

Comment: Yes the I=1 to 1 was intentional as it kept bombing for the other files.

Answer (score 0):

GO is a SQL Management Studio keyword,  not a T-SQL keyword, so the driver may be choking on that. GO causes a new SQL batch to start executing, and clears all previous context such as variables. However, There is a DDL restriction that states when creating a stored procedure, the CREATE PROC has to be the first keywords, so in your text file, I would still separate the CREATE PROC by GO, but execute each proc creation separately rather than sending them all in at once.

Answer (score 0):

I have never actually seen the parameters in a T-SQL create procedure statement enclosed in parens... Also, I don't think you need to use the word "As" when declaring your parames for a sproc (see below).

What happens if you remove the parens around the parameters? For example:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertDeal] 
    @DealID int
AS
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO Table1 (DealID, LoanID) SELECT @DealID as DealID, LOAN_ID FROM  ImportedLoans

    INSERT INTO Table2 (DealID, LoanID) SELECT @DealID as DealID, LOAN_ID FROM ImportedLoans

END
```

I would get your syntax down in the T-SQL editor so that it works and then use that knowledge to generate your script.

Comment: My scripts run fine in SQL with or without the parenthesis.  I changed my code just to import 1 stored procedure from the text file and it still bombs.  I was able to create the stored procedure directly from VB.NET and that seems to work, but since I have numerous stored procedures, I wanted to avoid creating 10-20 functions.

Comment: Can you paste the text file with the "1 procedure that bombs" and then also paste what you are putting into SQL that works fine? Thanks.

Comment: Since I have so many stored procedures (SP) I still wanted to be able to read them in from a text file and then programtically create all of the stored procedures.  After I read my SP file, I run a split command to save each SP as an item in an array and I could then run each stored procedure via a loop with this code:  
            sProcs = sb.ToString.Trim.Split(New String() {"CREATE"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
            For iSprocNumber = 0 To sProcs.Length - 1
                objCmd.CommandText = strProcedure
                objCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            Next

Comment: Without you sending the exact sql script that is failing, I am unable to help. Best of luck to you.

Comment: My Stored Procedure is too long and doesn't fit in the window.  Its runs perfectly after I parse each procedure into an array and then execute each procedure on its own.  Thanks for you assistance